# balance of two query result from different tables

Tags: mysql

Hi i have two table in my database 1. Income 2. Outcome 
Income table has ID, Date, Price also Outcome table exactly same im showing Sum of prices for today like that

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_gelen_gun = sprintf ("SELECT SUM(tutar) FROM cepbank WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())");
$gelen_gun = mysql_query($query_gelen_gun, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_gelen_gun = mysql_fetch_assoc($gelen_gun);
$totalRows_gelen_gun = mysql_num_rows($gelen_gun);

mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_giden_gun = sprintf ("SELECT SUM(tutar) FROM cepbank_out WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())");
$giden_gun = mysql_query($query_giden_gun, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_giden_gun = mysql_fetch_assoc($giden_gun);
$totalRows_giden_gun = mysql_num_rows($giden_gun);
```

.
.
.

```
<p>Total Income for Today:<?php echo $row_gelen_gun['SUM(tutar)']; ?></p>
<p>Total Outcome for Today:<?php echo $row_giden_gun['SUM(tutar)']; ?></p>
```

Now how i can show balance of this two result for example `$row_gelen_gun['SUM(tutar)']` = 100 and `$row_giden_gun['SUM(tutar)']` = 50

balance should be 100-50 =50 ?

Note: Price=tutar in query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to use `union all` or `cross join`.  Use `union all` to get the results in two rows.  Use `cross join` to get the results in two columns on the same row.

Here is an example for the `cross join`:

```
select sumcep, sumcepout
from (SELECT SUM(tutar) as sumcep
      FROM cepbank
      WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
     ) t cross join
     (SELECT SUM(tutar) as sumcepout
      FROM cepbank_out
      WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
     ) t2
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how i will complate balance=sumcep-sumcepout and show balance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Gordon's query, and if you want MySQL to calculate the balance just change the first line to this:

```
select sumcep, sumcepout, sumcep-sumcepout as balance
```

---

If you want to stay with your current approach (two separate queries), here are some recommendations:

First, I'd alias the columns because having them both named `SUM(tutar)` can be confusing. Also, I've always been uneasy about trusting the generated column name when a function is involved. So instead of these:

```
SELECT SUM(tutar) FROM cepbank WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
SELECT SUM(tutar) FROM cepbank_out WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
```

... try these:

```
SELECT SUM(tutar) AS Income FROM cepbank WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
SELECT SUM(tutar) AS Outcome FROM cepbank_out WHERE tarih >= DATE(NOW())
```

And then for balance you can do this:

```
$balance = $row_gelen_gun['Income'] - $row_giden_gun['Outcome'];
```

PHP will cast/convert to number for you.

BTW, you can use `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `DATE(NOW())`, but that's minor. Change if you think it makes the query more readable - your call :)

But most importantly, if this is anything more than a school assignment or a learning exercise, please please use `PDO` or `MySQLi`. Even if it is a learning exercise, try getting it to work as is and then converting to PDO or MySQLi - you'll need to use them in the "real world".

Comment: select sumcep, sumcepout, sumcep-sumcepout as balance this is solved my question thank you i am using dreamweaver it is creating codes for me then im editting when i need I'm just start to coding i will learn what is MySQLi and PDO thank you very much for your help